# Laying bricks/blocks into a concrete slab during the pour

Tags: concrete, brick, design

It is common practice to put a brick ribbon around a newly poured concrete walkway. Is it possible to put decorative designs, using bricks, in the middle of a concrete slab as it's poured? How do I put elements like paver bricks, or regular bricks, or blocks in the middle of concrete? Is this advisable, or does it cause cracks to develop?

Comment: There is already one answer assuming this is **after the walkway has been poured**. There are other options if this is **before** pouring the concrete. What is your situation?

Comment: @manassehkatz  This is before pouring.   So the question is at the time they are pouring concrete how do you place decorative elements like bricks or larger blocks in the middle. If this is not practical or advised then I guess the "after solution" is the way to go.

Comment: Not a full answer because I don't have personal experience (hopefully someone who does can speak up). I think a reasonable way to do this is to build forms using lumber to block out the sections where you will be installing brick - e.g., similar to the way you might have a lot of extra "edges" around other landscape features and different heights for steps, etc. Then after the concrete has cured you install the bricks or pavers in those inset areas.

Comment: You could also wrap the bricks with plastic, work them into the pour, and remove the wrapper later.

Comment: There are stamps you can use during the pour to make the concrete look like decorative bricks.

Comment: +1 for the stamps and staining idea.  You can get a lot of different patterns, but the concrete would be solid and there's no actual pavers to worry about.

Comment: @isherwood If you “press bricks into the pour” be prepared for cracks in the concrete.

Comment: I don't know why you're addressing me with  that tidbit, but concrete cracks regardless and needs to be controlled with... control joints. A few bricks don't change that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pouring my monolith foundation for our shed, we ran a couple bags short and couldn't send the concrete driver out for more. So our concrete finishers took some old brick and concrete blocks we had lying around and used it for filler. Not exactly the same situation as what you're asking, but it does answer:

- Yes, it is something you can do
- Yes, it is semi-common practice

Now, when I poured my walkway, I put flagstone, broken marble and other quary, and broken, colored glass as I was pouring it. The trick is to keep as close to the surface as you can, so when the brushed(?) finish happens, you can easily scrub off the concrete residue left on the top of your decorative pieces. If it's a smooth finish, it's a little more challenging to do during the pour. If you're doing it your self, you need to account for the volume your objects will consume so you do not over pour. If you have a contractor doing it, then just let them know before they begin that you want these pieces included into the pour. You should already decided the finish with them and they can decide when to place them.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

We use “blockouts” to create a space for bricks or blocks to be mortared into after the concrete sets. (We use wood boards that are tapered slightly for easy removal out of the concrete.)

Anytime you thicken or reduce concrete you’re liable to get a crack. Therefore, we add rebar in the concrete perpendicular to where the blockouts are added.